# Setting up mail server on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, postfix, mail-server

I need help on setting up a mail server on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 with a web interface for sandbox testing, tried using postfix and exim4 and it does not seems to work.

My main concern is to setup a mail server to simulate the sending and receiving of email. I need it to run on my cuckoo sandbox for the scanning process.

Appreciate all the help that the experts can give.

To be precise, I tried almost all the tutorials on both web and youtube, and I also tried squirrelmail for web gui, it shows the login page and after the login it pops a IMAP error.

Answer (score 0):

First, Sending/Receiving rely on the `SMTP` protocol. Dovecot, is NOT a `SMTP` server, it's an `IMAP`/`POP3` server, which is used to serve Mailboxes to the end user.

To receive mail you need a `SMTP` server, like `Postfix` or `Exim4`.
To send Mail, you need a `SMTP` client, like `sendmail`.

If you want to add a Web Interface, you'll also need a WebServer (Like `Apache2` or `Nginx`) and a web application like `Roundcube`.

Do not forget that if you want to test mail sending/receiving in almost real-world condition, it could be a good idea to add a `DNS` Server, like `Bind9`.

Comment: yes. I do note that. However i tried all the tutorial on web and youtube, and it does not seems to work.

Comment: Then, you need to be more precise on your question. What is not working, what have you tried etc... We can't just, by magic, give you the answer. The more general the question is, the more general the answer is.

Comment: I am sorry, quite new to forum...